# Error while making json api call in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter

I am facing below error

> ```
> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Insecure socket connections are disallowed by platform: 111.11.111.11
> ```

while executing the below json api call to the server in flutter application

```
var response = await http.post(loginapiUrl, body: data);
```

I cannot configure `https://` for my url. please provide me the solution

Comment: Are you testing on localhost?

Comment: @Khal no I am not testing on local host

Comment: okay so i assume that you're on c panel you can found how to create ssl from this website https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9418/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-your-server-using-cpanel

Comment: @Khal is there anyway to use `http://`only, by any means, because earlier this was working , now to my surprise, it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add network configuration in Android and iOS respectively as you are acessing the Insecure Connections.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

In respective folder add those thing inside the AndroidManifest.

For more instruction follow this.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Comment: Venky, How can I add network configuration for iOS?

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: @VickySingh https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android